# android graphic stack ' s library

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have spent some time to google information about graphic stack of android. But everywhere I saw pictures like it and text was described it. 
http://withimagination.imgtec.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/AndroigGFX2.png
But , unfortunately , nothing wrote about names of library which contained this components of graphics stack. Can you help me in it? Particulary , I want to know all about openGL ES calling and library.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL and OpenGL-ES are industry standard graphics APIs. They're not specific to Android but available on most platforms. They're extensively documented at https://www.opengl.org/registry/ and http://www.khronos.org/opengles/

I'd start by reading the specifications. Also there's an excellent OpenGL tutorial at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut